# Same Primary Key Pointing to Multiple Values in a Column. Insertion in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am unable to do and find that how can I insert multiple values in a single column associated with single primary key.

**This is what I expect to be in my sql databse:**
 [image]

- ***I have enabled auto increment for the primary key (packageid)***
- ***serviceidF is a foreign key***

  ```
     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
              query = "Insert Into tbl_Packages (packageName, 
              packagePrice, serviceId_F) values ('" + _ppnM3 + "', '" + 
              _pppM3 + "', '" + _i1M3 + "')";
              cmd = new SqlCommand(query, PC.connect());
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              PC.disconnect();

            }
          else if (i == 1)
          {
              query1 = "Insert Into tbl_Packages (packageName, 
              packagePrice, serviceId_F) values ('" + _ppnM3 + "', '" + 
              _pppM3 + "', '" + _i2M3 + "')";
              cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, PC.connect());
              cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
              PC.disconnect();
          }
       }
  ```

**This is what my query is doing (I know that I have enabled auto increment in primary id):**
[image]

Comment: If your packageId is primary key, then it wont allow you to insert Same value in multiple rows. PK allows not null and Unique values. Please check your data model.

Comment: @RajPaliwal I know that PK allows not null and Unique values. I am asking for the solution to get multiple values for a single field associated with one primary key.

Comment: Please try to create `composite primary` key with multiple columns. Please note in this case the combination of all the values must be unique. where it can accept same value for `PackageId` but rest columns must be unique

Comment: For this, I think you should use another table as the details table.

Comment: @Hasnain if it's a PK it can't have multiple rows associated with it. That's how databases work. The solution depends on the relation between packages and services. If it's one-to-many, ie each Service can only be related to one Package, put a `PackageID` column in your Services table. Otherwise create a separate table, eg `PackageServices` with PackageId and ServiceId columns that are both part of the PK

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is wrong if you think you need multiple PKs with the same values.  Part of the definition of PK is uniqueness.

Also, use parameters not string concatenation.

Also, what's with the `for`....`if` ?  You've just made 2 statements very complicated!

Perhaps you're missing an actual "package" table and what you are building is a "sub package" table where the package ID is a FK not a PK.  Very hard to tell though.

Comment: Ignore that for loop ! There is a development logic behind it. Just tell me how to get multiple values associated with one primary key in a single column.

Comment: @Hasnain LoztInSpace's answer explains that a PK is unique *by definition*. If you want to associate multiple values with it, store them in separate columns in the same row. Or use a *different* table to store related data.

Comment: Different table!